# PHP exec not working for compiling on Windows 8 through Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt

Tags: php, windows, compilation, visual-studio-2013, exec

Thank you for taking the time to help me today. I have what I hope is a simple question. I have been attempting to use php exec() or any related PHP command to Open up the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013 and use it to compile a file and save the output to a file on my local machine. I have it working fine from Run on Windows, but I can't seem to get it to work with PHP exec(). Here is how I have the command set up currently.

> `$cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat && cd C:\wamp\www\csc424Try3\app\uploads && cl /EHsc basic.cpp && basic >> C:\wamp\www\csc424Try3\app\outputs\output.txt';`
>
> `exec($cmd, $result);`

As you can see, I am chaining together commands. The first command allows the prompt to open, the second changes to the proper directory, the third runs the command for compiling in the prompt, and the fourth outputs to a text file.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I had a feeling it had something to do with formatting, but perhaps chaining the commands together does not work in PHP the way it does on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting quotes around most of your arguments in the exec call's string, meaning that things like `Program Files` will be seen as two separate things, not a single directory.

```
$cmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\....VsDevCmd.bat" && etc...';
        ^--                                     ^-- need these
```

as is, you're trying to execute a program called `C:\Program`, with some extra arguments like `Files (x86)\.....`.

Comment: I see what you mean! I did not even consider that, so thank you. I tried it out and my command now looks like below.
$cmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && "cd C:\wamp\www\csc424Try3\app\uploads" && "cl /EHsc basic.cpp" && "basic >> C:\wamp\www\csc424Try3\app\outputs\output.txt"';

I am still getting the same results and the file is not compiling however. :( Perhaps it has something to do with the way I am chaining commands with && ?

Comment: are you running this under a webserver? remember that the web server user (e.g. IUSR_IIS) has very limited permissions and may not have the rights to even access/execute the batch file, let alone actually compile/write new files.

Comment: also be very careful using backslashes for paths in PHP on Windows in double-quoted strings. It's not the case here, but if you have something like `"c:\tabulations"`, `\t` will be treated as a tab character, not a letter t. In general, you should use forward slashes for all your paths - PHP will auto-translate to the OS-specific separators for you.

Comment: I am running this on localhost through wampserver. I never took into consideration that permissions might be restricted. I'll have to research and look to see if there is a way around t. 
Also, thank you for letting me know about the backslashes! I did not know that, so I'll keep it in mind for now on.

Comment: So, I escaped the backslashes and also tried forward-slashes. Unfortunately, it didn't work! It now looks like this.
$cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat" && "cd C:\\wamp\\www\\csc424Try3\\app\\uploads" && "cl /EHsc basic.cpp" && "basic >> C:\\wamp\\www\\csc424Try3\\app\\outputs\\output.txt"';
            exec($cmd);

Now, about the idea with IIS, I'm running through Wampserver at the time and don't have IIS started at all. I have the permissions on the specific folders I'm using to allow full access also!

Comment: doesn't matter what webserver you're using. the user account it's running as has to have access. and that's not just to the specific folders you're actually using files in. it has to be ALL the parent folders as well. e.g. you can put a "free, take one" box inside a bank vault, but no one can actually take one because the vault is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question after some research. The way I was trying to do it before just wasn't working. After talking to a colleague, I thought writing a .bat file for the background would work better, and it absolutely did. I wrote the chain of commands in a .bat file and executed it like follows;

system("cmd /c C:\wamp\www\csc424Try3\app\uploads\stuff.bat");

Success! The file can now be successfully compiled and ran from PHP. :) It is a good day.